# Add attribute through commandline in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, command-line-interface, samba, windows

I am migrating from OpenLDAP to Active Directory (Samba4). I was wondering if there is a commandline command (in windows commandprompt or powershell) to add Attributes to the Active Directory Schema.

I can at the moment only add attributes through the Active Directory Schema snap in in mmc /a but as I have a lot of attributes I'm searching for a commandline solution.

Comment: Why can't you use PowerShell? That seems like a silly restriction in 2013, like saying you can only write scripts in `/bin/sh`

Comment: Edited it, im just not so familiar with powershell yet. But if you have a powershell solution I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Do you need the tool to be scriptable? Can you generate the schema deltas beforehand? See this TechNet [Methods for Extending the Schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961584.aspx) for examples of what I'm asking about.

Comment: @timmeyh Why are you adding a lot of attributes? That seems exceedingly odd.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to handle this is typically by making an ldf file [as described in this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.05.schema.aspx) and import/apply It with ldifde.exe on the Schema Master in your forest.